# c++ - map - get the key of this value

Tags: c++, winapi, dictionary

I have a std::map of windows, for example:

```
class MyWindow
{
public:
    MyWindow()
    {
        CreateWindow(...);
    }
    ... // rest of code
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        // code
    }
}

std::map<string, MyWindow> windows;
```

And inside the WndProc function I want to know which window is now in the function, how can I get the key of this window.

Comment: when iterating, windows->first?

Comment: I am inside the WndProc function I want to know which window is now in the function

Comment: I don't see why you'd use an `std::map` for that.

Comment: what do you mean with "window is in the function"? I don't get the meaning of that.

Comment: What WndProc function? You don't have one. Your question lacks clarity and cohesion.

Comment: "I want to know which window is now in the function" ... in *what* function?

Comment: @Lightness Races - I have WndProc for this window class, and the WndProc function run for all the windows of this window class, so I want to know which window function currently handled

Comment: Sorry but your question is still nonsensical. Provide some context

Comment: @all - see my edit of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to store a pointer to an object (`this` if you're creating a window in a class method) for a given `HWND`. Use `GWLP_USERDATA` as `nIndex` argument.

This way, you need no map at all: when you have a window handle, `GetWindowLongPtr` is enough to get an object.

Answer (score 1):

If the `MyWindow` contains the windows handle (`HWND`) then you could use e.g. [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the instance.

Something like:

```
HWND hWnd;  // The window handle to look for

auto windowIterator = std::find_if(std::begin(windows), std::end(windows),
    [hWnd](const std::map<std::string, MyWindow>::value_type& p) -> bool {
        return (p.first.getNativeWindowHandle() == hWnd);
    });
if (windowIterator != std::end(windows))
{
    // `windowIterator` now "points" to the window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a brute-force search of the map:

```
auto it = std::find_if(windows.begin(), windows.end(),
                       [this](std::pair<std::string const, MyWindow> const & p) -> bool
                       { return p.second == *this; } );

if (it == windows.end()) { /* not found */ }
else                     { /* window key is it->first */ }
```

If the objects are unique, you might also be able to say `&p.second == this` in the comparison.

Comment: Don't you mean `std::find_if`? :)